# How to convert a non-linear constraint to a linear constraint?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming, linearization

How to convert non-linear constraint $s_{k} = \min(t_i y_{ik})$ to MIP constraint?

Here, $t_i$ is a positive decision variable and $y_{ik}$ is a binary decision variable.

Comment: The answer depends in part on whether the rest of the model ensures that the solver will take the smallest feasible value of $s_k$ (for instance, the objective minimizes $s_k$ and it does not appear in any other constraint) or not (something else in the model might put upward pressure on the value of $s_k$).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed,  $s_k$  is the start time of turning a machine and it is used only in the objective function, we minimize $(f_k -s_k)*cost $ which means the cost of executing a machine must be minimized.

Comment: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binary-variable

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: This answers the question as posted, which (based on a comment below) is apparently not what was intended. I have a second answer below for what I believe was intended.

Given the clarification in the comment, it should be sufficient to enforce $s_k \le t_i \cdot y_{ik}$ for all $i.$ Since cost is a decreasing function of $s_k,$ any optimal solution will automatically use the largest possible value of $s_k.$

Assuming you know an upper bound $T_i$ for $t_i,$ you just need the following constraints for each $k:$
$$s_k \le t_i\quad\forall i$$
and
$$s_k \le T_i\cdot y_{ik}\quad\forall i.$$
If any $y_{ik}$ is 0, $s_k$ will be 0. Otherwise, $s_k$ will be set to the smallest $t_i.$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added these constraints to my model and ran it, but the value of $sk$ is zero for all i.  How can I enforce this constraint $s_k<=t_i$  when $y_{ik}==1$.

Comment: Something may be wrong with your model. Assuming your costs are positive, for a given value of $f_k$ you minimize $c\cdot (f_k - s_k)$ (where $c>0$ is the cost parameter) by maximizing $s_k.$ So the solver would set $s_k=0$ only if it were forced to, meaning either some $t_i = 0$ or some $y_{ik}=0.$ Perhaps you misstated your requirement $(s_k = \min_i t_i\cdot y_{ik})$? Do you really want $s_k =0$ if any $y_{ik}=0?$

Comment: Indeed, I want $s_k=0$ when all $y_{ik}=0$ otherwise, $s_k=min  t_i$ when one or more tasks are assigned to machine $k$.  It should be noted that $(f_k- s_k)$ indicates the period of running machine $k$ and c>0. I have these constraints:        -----   1) $ s_k <= T.y_{ik}$    2)     $  s_k<=t_i  3)  F_{k} <= T. y_{ik}     4)F_{k}>= M_{i}- T. (1-y_{ik})$

Comment: OK, this is different from the question you originally asked. I will post a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following answers what appears to have been the intended question: how to model the constraint that $s_k = \min \lbrace t_i | y_{ik}=1 \rbrace$ with the minimum of an empty set taken to be 0 (i.e., $s_k=0$ if $y_{ik}=0$ for all $i.$

Assume that $i$ runs from 1 to $N$ and that $M_k$ is a valid upper bound for $s_k \ge 0.$ Introduce binary variables $z_{ik}$ for $i=0,\dots,N$ along with the following constraints:
$$\sum_{i=0}^N z_{ik}=1\quad (1)$$
$$z_{ik}\le y_{ik} \quad i=1,\dots,N\quad (2)$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^N y_{ik} \le N(1-z_{0k})\quad (3)$$
$$s_k = \sum_{i=1}^N t_i z_{ik} \quad (4)$$
$$s_k \le t_i + M_k(1 - y_{ik})\quad i=1,\dots,N\quad (5).$$
Variable $z_{ik}$ selects which $t_i$ will be the value of $s_k$ (or sets $s_k=0$ if $z_{0k}=1$). Constraint (4) enforces that, and constraint (1) enforces selection of a single $i.$ Constraint (2) says that we cannot select an $i\in \lbrace 1,\dots,N\rbrace$ unless $y_{ik}=1.$ Constraint (3) says that we can only set $z_{0k}=1$ if all $y_{ik}=0.$ Finally, constraint (5) ensures $s_k \le t_i$ whenever $y_{ik} = 1.$

An alternative to (3) is
$$y_{ik} \le 1-z_{0k}\quad i=1,\dots,N\quad (3').$$ (3') makes the formulation a bit larger but a bit tighter.

Comment: Thanks a million. The problem is sk=min{ti|yik=1}. But constraints (4) and (5) are nonlinear, and I do not know how to linearize these constraints.

Comment: Sorry, the nonlinearity in (5) was a typo, which I've fixed. Linearizing the product of a binary variable and a general variable, as in (4), is a frequently asked (and frequently answered) question on this site. Try the search bar.